# PhoneGap - iOS - Recurring In App Subscription - Purchase issues

Tags: ios, cordova, in-app-purchase

So I need to create an PhoneGap app that, during signup, requires a user to signup for a recurring monthly subscription.

I found this fine tutorial on PhoneGap In App purchases: https://fovea.cc/blog/index.php/3-steps-tutorial-for-phonegap-2x-in-app-purchase-on-ios/

And followed it (code is below).

So my issue is that I click the subscribe button, and walk through all of the dialogs from iOS, the onPurchase doesn't seem to be called...

If I close the app and come back in and the onPurchase gets called immediately, and then it is called each and every time I load the app.

One thought is that iOS is telling me that this user has an active subscription, which is cool...but it doesn't seem to tell me when the purchase was first successfully completed.

The buy button just says that they started the process...they can cancel out anytime, so I can't go off of that. I need to have something that tells me that the user has successfully signed up for my monthly subscription.

Thoughts?

```
var IAP = {
    list: [config.IAP],
    products: {}
};

// Called when I load the app on a device
function InitializePayment(){
    LogInfo("Loading IAPs " + IAP.list[0]);

    // Check availability of the storekit plugin
    if (!window.storekit) {
        HandleError('In-App Purchases not available');
        return;
    }

    storekit.init({
        ready: IAP.onReady,
        purchase: IAP.onPurchase,
        restore: IAP.onRestore,
        error: IAP.onError
    });
}

// IN APP PAYMENT

IAP.onReady = function () {
    // Once setup is done, load all product data.
    storekit.load(IAP.list, function (products, invalidIds) {
        LogInfo('IAPs Loaded...');

        for (var j = 0; j < products.length; ++j) {
            var p = products[j];
            LogInfo('Loaded IAP(' + j + '). title:' + p.title + ' description:' + p.description + ' price:' + p.price + ' id:' + p.id);
            IAP.products[p.id] = p;
        }

        IAP.loaded = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < invalidIds.length; ++i) {
            HandleError("Error: could not load " + invalidIds[i]);
        }
    });
};

IAP.onPurchase = function (transactionId, productId, receipt) {
    LogInfo("IAP Purchase Success!!!");
    LogInfo("Transaction: " + transactionId);
    LogInfo("Product: " + productId);
    LogInfo("Receipt: " + receipt);

    var n = (_localStorage['storekit.' + productId]|0) + 1;
    _localStorage['storekit.' + productId] = n;

    if (IAP.purchaseCallback) {
        IAP.purchaseCallback(productId);
        delete IAP.purchaseCallback;
    }

    PaymentSignup(transactionId, receipt, function() {
        MovePageLeft("#pageSignupWelcome", _currentPage);
    });
};

IAP.onError = function (errorCode, errorMessage) {
    if (errorMessage == 'Cannot connect to iTunes Store'){
        // this just means that they cancelled a payment...no problem.
        return;
    }

    HandleError('IAP Error: ' + errorMessage);
};

IAP.buy = function (productId, callback) {
    LogInfo("User clicked the subscribe button. Woot.");
    IAP.purchaseCallback = callback;
    storekit.purchase(productId);
};

IAP.onRestore = function (transactionId, productId, transactionReceipt) {
    var n = (localStorage['storekit.' + productId]|0) + 1;
    localStorage['storekit.' + productId] = n;
};

IAP.restore = function () {
    storekit.restore();
};

var renderIAPs = function (el) {
    if (IAP.loaded) {
        var html = "<ul>";
        for(var id in IAP.products) {
            var prod = IAP.products[id];
            html += "<li>" +
         "<div class='iapTitle'>" + prod.title + "</div>" +
         "<div class='iapDescription'>" + prod.description + "</div>" +
         "<button type='button' " +
         "onclick='IAP.buy(\"" + id + "\")'>Subscribe</button>" +
         "</li>";
        }
        html += "</ul>";
        el.innerHTML = html;
    }
    else {
        el.innerHTML = "In-App Purchases not available.";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have direct experience with this plugin but I checked the open issues on GitHub and found issue [#343](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/issues/343) which mentions the purchase method being called continuously on load.

Issue #343 references issue [#303](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/issues/303) as a possible solution with the underlying problem relating to consumable downloads.  The fix is in version 4.1.0.

Which version of iOS and plugin are you running?

Comment: I am running 4.0...will check 4.1. Thanks!